# Qt сделать окно квадратным

Tags: c++, qt, ui, design

Как сделать MainWindow квадратным? Нужно чтобы окно можно было растягивать, но при этом его высота и ширина оставались одинаковыми.

Comment: Можно переопределить resizeEvent и в нем устанавливать одинаковую ширину и высоту через метод resize. Пример на pyqt (c++/qt creator у меня не стоят, то там тоже самое): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2ed92750d1f4403f92616d6f4b64e4e9742b5bd9/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__square_change_in_size__resizeEvent.py